# Use findIndex and exclude old browsers

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I would like to use the findIndex method and exclude all browsers that do not support this method - specially old friends like <= IE11.

I assumed that I could solve the problem via an `if / else` statement:

```js
var albums = [
    {
        title: "Hash-Bar Loops",
        artist: "Deepchord",
        releasedate: "2011-06-27",
        label: "Soma Records",
        playtime: "1:19:23"
    },
    {
        title: "Liumin",
        artist: "Deepchord",
        releasedate: "2010-01-01" /* first match of findIndex - 1 */,
        label: "Modern Love",
        playtime: "1:19:28"
    },
    {
        title: "Coldest Season",
        artist: "Deepchord",
        releasedate: "2007-01-01",
        label: "Modern Love",
        playtime: "1:19:43"
    },
    {
        title: "Sommer",
        artist: "Deepchord",
        releasedate: "2012-08-27",
        label: "Soma Records",
        playtime: "1:14:36"
    },
    {
        title: "Atmospherica Vol. 2",
        artist: "Deepchord",
        releasedate: "2016-02-05",
        label: "Soma Records",
        playtime: "0:25:14"
    }
];

function init() {
    "use strict";

    if (Array.findIndex in window) {
        var first = albums.findIndex(function(album, index, albums) {
            return new Date(album.releasedate).getMonth() + 1 === 1;
        });

        console.log(first); /* 1 */
    } else {
        console.log("Sorry - old browser");
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

In IE11, however, I get an error message that causes the statements in the else-block to stop executing:

> The object does not support the property or method findIndex.

Also tried `try / catch` but got the same message.

How can I get modern browsers to use findIndex and old browsers to ignore the corresponding area in the script?

Comment: The test should be `if(typeof Array.prototype.findIndex === "function")` or `if("findIndex" in Array.prototype)` or `if(Array.prototype.hasOwnProperty("findIndex"))`.

Comment: ... or in your case you can use `albums` like: `if(typeof albums.findIndex === "function")` or just `if(albums.findIndex)`.

Comment: Make polyfills, not exclusions.

Comment: ....seems a bit over the top. I use a modern and lean form of programming and must implement an extensive one-off for an old broswser ... Nevertheless: thank you all for your comments and help !